# Why we have to mention ACCESS KEY and SECURITY KEY two time when we import vmdk files to ec2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, vmdk

Following is the code I found in web

```
ec2-import-volume xxx.vmdk -f vmdk -b <S3 bucket name> -O
    <ACCESS KEY> -W <SECURITY KEY> -o <ACCESS KEY> -w <SECURITY KEY>
    -z <your zone, ex:-ap-southeast-1a> --region <your region, ex:-
    ap-southeast-1>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see that in the description of ec2-import-volume at the [EC2 CLI documentation](http://awsdocs.s3.amazonaws.com/EC2/ec2-clt.pdf).

The syntax is documented as:

> ec2-import-volume disk_image  -f  file_format  [-s  volume_size ] -z 
>   availability_zone  [- b  s3_bucket_name ] **[-o  owner ] -w  secret_key** 
>   [--prefix  prefix ] [--manifest-url  url ] [-d description ] [--x 
>   days ] [--ignore-region-affinity] [--dry-run] [--no-upload] [--dont-
>   verify-format]

That said, the EC2 CLI is a legacy tool and has, for most purposes, been superseded by the unified [AWSCLI](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/).